# A single word for two and four wheeled vehicles

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there any single word that signifies both two and four wheeled vehicles. i.e. Cars and Motorcycles?

Comment: A *motorised conveyance*?

Comment: "Vehicle", according to most laws in the US.  If you want to exclude non-motorized bicycles it's a "motorized vehicle".

Comment: Do you need to exclude three wheel vehicles like Bombardier Spyder? Six wheel vehicles such as two axle pickup trucks with 4 wheels on the rear axle; or 3 axle trucks?

Answer (score 3):

A ***wheeled vehicle*** is a general expression you may use:

> - a vehicle that moves on wheels and usually has a container for transporting things or people.

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

A *vehicle* seems a likely choice--though it technically could mean any vehicle (boat, auto, motorcycle, space-ship or plane) you're most likely to hear it used with land vehicles.

Examples: "Please step away from the vehicle." or "Please step out of the vehicle."

Comment: Technically, "vehicle" includes bicycles (in the US).  "Motorized vehicle" is the term for a car, truck, or motorcycle.

Comment: TBH, I've never heard anyone refer to a bicycle as a vehicle, but I'm sure it happens.

Comment: Most US states refer to bicycles as "vehicles" in their traffic laws.

Comment: I'm just trying to imagine a cop saying to a bike rider, "I need you to step away from the vehicle, mam."